# Convert simple string to Required Format : PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to Convert simple string to set based on below logic

if string is `3,4-8-7,5` then I need the set as `(3,8,7),(4,8,5)`.

The Logic behind to building the set are we need to consider ',' as OR condition and '-' as AND condition.

I am trying my best using For loop :

```
$intermediate = array();

$arry_A = explode('-', '3,4-8-7,5');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arry_A); $i++) {

    $arry_B = explode(',', $arry_A[$i]);

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arry_B); $j++) {  

        if (count($intermediate) > 0) {

            for ($k = 0; $k < count($intermediate); $k++) { 

                $intermediate[$k] = $intermediate[$k] . ',' . $arry_B[$j];

            }

        } elseif (count($intermediate) === 0) {

            $intermediate[0] = $arry_B[$j];

        }        

    }
}
```

`echo $intermediate`, should give final result.

Comment: What about `(3,8,5)` and `(4,8,7)`?

Comment: Also, it looks like you are giving `OR` (`,`) higher precedence than `AND` (`-`). Is that correct?

Comment: The Expression must be evaluated from Left to Right. I do not require precedence. For more info: Another Example is: If string is "4-5,6-4" then required set will be (4,5,4),(4,6,4)

Comment: I would like to give clear example: if string is  5-6,7,8-2,3-1. It need to be divided first like [5] AND [(6) OR (7) OR (8)] AND [(2) OR (3)] AND [1]. Result must be All possible combination: (5,6,2,1),(5,6,3,1),(5,7,2,1),(5,7,3,1),(5,8,2,1),(5,8,3,1).

Answer (score 0):

This Code works correctly, Try this

```
<?php
    $intermediate = array();
    $str="";
    $val='3,4-8-7,5';
    $vals=str_replace(',','-',$val);
    $j=1;
    $arry_A = explode('-',$vals );
    $str.='(';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arry_A); $i++) {

        if($j==3){
            $str.=$arry_A[$i].',';
            $str.='),';
            $str.='(';
            $j=1;
        }
       else
            $str.=$arry_A[$i].',';
        $j++;
    }
    echo substr($str, 0, -2);
?>
```

Comment: Could you please see my updated comments and give the direction(s) or solution. Expecting your inputs.